# Using StringBuilder in multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have seen code where people have used StringBuffer most of the times just to avoid any issues with multiple threads but i am not able to come  to a general case (most of the times) where StringBuffer is required.

If i have a method like below - `private String getPath(){
      return new StringBuilder("a").append("b").toString();
}`

Even though this method will be used by multiple threads  it should be okay. (?)
Because we are creating a new Stringbuilder and every thread will have its own copy on stack (reference).

Only if we were getting a StringBuilder as method argument will it be a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Even though this method will be used by multiple threads it should be okay. " ? The main issue with multithreading (if no locks are implemented) is the coherence of shared data. If you share a string between several threads and some of them can write to it, each thread may read a different string value. If you create a new (constant value) string from the function each time, there is no such issue, but you could just as well return a const string value anyway. So I assume you intend to return the value of some variable, correct?

Comment: Take above case (example), here each thread will call getPath() method which instantiate a new StringBuilder each time and returns a string (which is immutable). So, do i need to use StringBuffer in this case?

Comment: Of course synchronization is only needed when we have concurrency on the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is right. Each thread calling `getPath` will create a new `StringBuilder` and of course different threads are allowed to work on different `StringBuilder` objects in parallel. So you don't need to use `StringBuffer` here.

When passing a `StringBuilder` as parameter to `getPath` you would have a problem. But `StringBuffer` would not help in this case either because different threads would be appending to the same `StringBuffer` and `getPath` could return a mixture like "aab". You would need a global locking at the start and end of the `getPath` method while using the passed `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `StringBuilder` is a member of your class, this might be important for you.

So you could actually decide to use it for gathering text into a buffer, before outputting it all at the end of some task.

```
class Gatherer {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    public void gatherEvent(Object o) {

        buffer.append(o);
    }

    public String toString() {

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public void reset() {

        buffer.setLength(0);
    }
}
```

You would prefer to use StringBuffer in a multithreaded environment so that concurrent invocations of `gather` wouldn't clobber one another. Of course there are better ways to do this, such as storing in array of `Object[]` and lazy evaluating in `toString()`.

You could add an optimisation too where rather than creating a new instance every time you could just reset the buffer, which is what the `reset` function above demonstrates.